# How to send a complete closure better

Tags: ios, swift

What I want is to send a `closures` to a `UIViewController` to tell it what it will do in the end. But when it comes to a package of `UIViewControllers` it will be a little messy.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var complete: ()->()

    init(complete: ()->()){
        self.complete = complete
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    private var complete: ()->()

    init(complete: ()->()){
        self.complete = complete
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Here are my `UIViewControllers`. What want to do is to send a complete closure to UIViewController2, but I have to push UIViewController first. So what I have to do is send the closure to `UIViewController`, then UIViewController send the closure to UIViewController2. It is not messy when there are only two `UIViewControllers`. But it will be very messy when there comes out a package of `UIViewControllers`.

Any better solutions?

Comment: you can make a singleton to hold the handle,but the best way is pass them one by one(which seems messy).

Answer (score 1):

You the following code to handle the completion handler

First, create a base class of UIViewController and define the completionHandler

```
import UIKit

public class MyController: UIViewController {

var completionHandler: ((Bool, String) -> Void)? // Bool and String are the return type, you can choose anything you want to return

public func onComplete(completion : ((Bool, String) -> Void)?)
{
    self.completionHandler = completion
}

override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override public func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

In `ViewController1`, you need to call another `ViewController` like this

```
class ViewController: MyController {

// Initialization of view objects
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //You are loading another ViewController from current ViewController
    let controller2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controller2") as? MyController
    controller2?.onComplete({ (finished, event) in
        self.completionHandler?(finished, event)
    })
}

//This is your button action or could be any event on which you will fire the completion handler

@IBAction func buttonTapped()
{
    self.completionHandler(boolType, controllerName)
}
```

and where ever, you will create a new `ViewController` you will need to set its completionHandler by writing the line

```
controller2?.onComplete({ (finished, event) in
    self.completionHandler?(finished, event)
})
```

Comment: I know what you mean. Maybe i did not explain my question clear. I want to send a completion handler to ViewController3 or even ViewController10, but my navigation controller have to push some former view controllers. I have to send the completion handler one by one thorough the view controllers. I think it will be very messy when there comes plenty of view controllers.

Comment: But its ok na if you can set completion handler for all Viewcontroller, the code will like you have only on handler. Depends upon from where or on which event you will fire that handler

Comment: What i think is the other view controllers do not need the completion handler from the first to the end. Maybe package the list of view controllers is a way but make the logic even more messy :( Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If my answer really helps. I'm happy to help. :)